Problems integrating with Microsoft Office 365 through Azure
I am currently learning an automation tool called UIPath. A lot of the concept should relate to some of the general stuff done with object-orientation programming. I am currently trying to integrate with Office 365 through Azure. After I enter the application ID and Tenant ID on my application tool, I am prompted to login. However, everytime I do this, I received a sign-in error that prevents me from logging in:

Is there any reason why this is happening? What can I do to resolve this?
